# Paypal In-Context Express Checkout button missing on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, paypal

I have implemented Paypal's In-Context Express Checkout on a website (HTML and JQuery, no shopping cart, no CMS or anything), and it works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome for Windows, and Safari, Firefox, Chrome & Opera for Mac, but it doesn't work on IE.

Paypal's "Paypal Checkout" button is missing on IE. Every other browser has a button inserted which is the one that is clicked on to "activate" the checkout flow, but on IE the button is missing and thus the checkout flow is not activated.

The problem is ONLY on Internet Explorer. IE11, using `X-UA-Compatible IE=EDGE`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what specific version of IE it doesn't work with? are you sure that those versions of IE's Quirks Mode and Compatibility View are disabled?

Comment: I'm using IE 11, in EDGE mode. @Roman

Comment: ok thanks,..one more check, you've added <!DOCTYPE html> in the page correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the DOCTYPE I'm using. The problem I've detected is that Paypal's checkout.js is supposed to insert into my form a span with a button, which works in all browsers except for Internet Explorer. That's the button that submits the form and opens the pop up. If I submit the form without the button it will just redirect instead of opening the popup.

Comment: just for fun, what happens if you change it to content="IE=9" or content="IE=10"? :)

Comment: I tried but that didn't work, but while I was fiddling with it, I noticed that I had placed the checkout.js script tag in the head on the document and I moved it to the body, directly before my form tag and it started working. -_- I have no idea what the difference is, but it works now!

Comment: @Roman thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that by moving the `<script>` tag with checkout.js from the `<head>` to the `<body>` right before the `<form>` tag, it works on IE.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your integration but I'm guessing you're calling `window.paypalCheckoutReady` far later than the script is being inserted into the page and run, which will mean the `paypalCheckoutReady` event has already fired. To mitigate this and to prevent blocking the page load, the script tag should be at the end of your page before the closing `</body>` tag, and have the `async` attribute added to it.